# Is Defense cumulative or individual?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

Some enemy Monsters have Defense. If you don't do more damage than their Defense, each attack only deals the minimum amount of damage (1). To overcome their Defense, must any given team member do more damage than their Defense, or can the sum of my team's damage overcome their Defense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Attacks have to beat defense individually.**

Each card attacks twice (assuming it has a sub-element and you made matches of both colors) and defense is applied separately to each attack. This can best be observed by attacking a high defense monster such that only your highest-attack card is able to beat the monster's defense. All of the other attacks will show their effective damage (the number that appears on the monster) as 1, while the one attack that beats defense will do more damage.

Many team builds will bring a single high-damage card (multiple TPA awakenings or a killer awakening) when a dungeon contains a high-defense low-HP monster, since they only need that one card to break through.